# Avoid multiple redirects in contao

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, contao

I have analyzed my website with the portal web.dev from Google. This told me that I have too many redirects if I call the URL without www and with http:
It goes first to https and without www, then to http with www and only then to https and www.
This is my htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Allow access from all domains for webfonts (see contao/core-bundle#528)
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?|font\.css)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<files serviceaccount.json>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

`</IfModule>`

I don't see at all where these redirects are implemented. I also found this variant to redirect directly. Even if I put them in the htaccess file, the redirects remain as described above.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can you tell me how all these redirects come about and why the last code snippet doesn't work?

Comment: Can you test in a new browser or clear your browser cache.

Comment: Done, same problem...

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: @anubhava http://xyz.de 301 -> https://xyz.de 301 -> http://www.xyz.de 301 -> https://www.xyz.de 200

Comment: If that's the case then you have some more rules or code that are doing this redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Some of those redirects might be done by your Hoster. Also, in newer Contao versions, Contao automatically redirects to `https` in the front end, if HTTPS is enabled in the respective website root's settings in the back end.

In any case, you should implement the redirects yourself, e.g. in your `web/.htaccess`. For example:

```
# Redirect to www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

*Note:* the www redirect would redirect *any* domain that does not start with `www.` to `www.`. If you have a multidomain setup with different subdomains, you will need to adjust the `www.` redirect accordingly.